# Code does not give any result and there is no syntax error

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I get no results.

This may be the answer you’re looking for. If not, try removing or changing your filters to make them less specific."

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS Cham_camera, DATE(t2.time) AS time2, t2.tagID
FROM
    sc_analytics.ugc_post_created AS t2
WHERE
    t2.content_src = "camera"
    AND t2.Composetype = "video"
    AND t2.Language = "Tamil"
    AND CAST(t2.userId AS INT64) IN (SELECT * 
                                     FROM `maximal-furnace-783.sc_analytics`.championsId)
    AND CAST(DATE(t2.`time`) AS timestamp) BETWEEN CAST(DATE_ADD(DATE(current_timestamp), interval -2 day) AS timestamp) 
                                               AND CAST(DATE(current_timestamp()) AS timestamp)
GROUP BY 
    2, 3
```

> "No results!
>   This may be the answer you’re looking for. If not, try removing or changing your filters to make them less specific."

I expect a table with time and tagID grouped champions camera content

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  No rows match your conditions, so you are getting an empty result set.

Comment: Remove one condition at the time and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that looks like no results from the filters you have used. 
Try to run the below part of the query and see if you are getting any results:

```
 SELECT count(*) as Cham_camera, date(t2.time) as time2, t2.tagID from
 sc_analytics.ugc_post_created as t2
```

and then try adding the conditions as needed.